# How do I set $? or the return code in Bash?

Tags: bash, error-handling, return-value, exit-code

I want to set a return value once so it goes into the while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ $? -eq 1 ]
do
#do something until it returns 0    
done
```

In order to get this working I need to set `$? = 1` at the beginning, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

RC=1

while [ $RC -eq 1 ]
do

  #do something until it returns 0    

  RC=$?
done
```

Answer (score 165):

You can set an arbitrary exit code by executing `exit` with an argument in a subshell.

```
$ (exit 42); echo "$?"
42
```

So you could do:

```
(exit 1)    # or some other value > 0 or use false as others have suggested
while (($?))
do
    # do something until it returns 0    
done
```

Or you can [emulate a `do while` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16491478/26428):

```
while 
    # do some stuff
    # do some more stuff
    # do something until it returns 0    
do
    continue  # just let the body of the while be a no-op
done
```

Either of those guarantee that the loop is run at least one time which I believe is what your goal is.

For completeness, `exit` and `return` each accept an optional argument which is an integer (positive, negative or zero) which sets the return code as the remainder of the integer after division by 256. The current shell (or script or subshell*) is exited using `exit` and a function is exited using `return`.

Examples:

```
$ (exit -2); echo "$?"
254
$ foo () { return 2000; }; foo; echo $?
208
```

---

* This is true even for subshells which are created by pipes (except when both job control is disabled and `lastpipe` is enabled):

```
$ echo foo | while read -r s; do echo "$s"; exit 333; done; echo "$?"
77
```

Note that it's better to use `break` to leave loops, but its argument is for the number of levels of loops to break out of rather than a return code.

Job control is disabled using `set +m`, `set +o monitor` or `shopt -u -o monitor`. To enable `lastpipe` do `shopt -s laspipe`. If you do both of those, the `exit` in the preceding example will cause the `while` loop *and* the containing shell to *both* exit and the final `echo` there will not be performed.

Comment: Should be `$(exit 42); echo "$?"`

Comment: @ElliotChance: The dollar sign in my answer represents the prompt and works as-is. What you propose would also work, but isn't necessary.

Comment: Note that you can use the range 0-255 but what actually happens is a modulo against 256.  That means you can `exit 300` and $? will be `44`.  Also, `exit -1` would return `255` (a strange habit I've seen a lot).  Just something to be aware of.  It's best to just return the value you desire so stick to 0-255 so you (or someone else) won't get surprised.

Comment: @boweeb `-1 mod X == X-1` is pretty normal, you essentially continue the `0,1,...,X-1` sequence into negatives. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation for variations and rationale.

Comment: @toolforger -- yup... that's what I said above.  I'm not confused about the math.  I'm confused _why_ a developer would want to use a convoluted way to get to 255.  My best guess is the convention implies _the 255 return code isn't meant to be meaningful_ (and writing it as `-1` is marginally easier to write(?)).  RC 1 is common for a generic/unspecified error but I've never seen anything actually eval `$?` for 255 (specifically).

Answer (score 28):

`false` always returns an exit code of 1.

```
#!/bin/bash
false
while [ $? -eq 1 ]
do
#do something until it returns 0    
done
```

Answer (score 7):

Some of answers rely on rewriting the code. In some cases it might be a foreign code that you have no control over.

Although for this specific question, it is enough to set $? to 1, but if you need to set $? to any value - the only helpful answer is the one from Dennis Williamson's.

A bit more efficient approach, which does not spawn a new child (but is a also less terse), is:

```
function false() { echo "$$"; return ${1:-1}; }
false 42
```

Note: echo part is there just to verify it runs in the current process.

Comment: While I would avoid calling this function `false` (which could be confusing for readers), using a function is *significantly* faster than a subshell. A rough microbenchmark suggests more than 100x overhead with a subshell.

Comment: why confusing? does the same as a traditional false command, just improved as it allows you to set your preferred error value/

Comment: Because `false 2` will have different behavior depending on whether or not your function is in the environment.

Comment: all standard callers of false will still work (as false is only expected to return nonzero). the only really confusing part is calling it false 0 (which should maybe throw an error to avoid confusion). so it does not break anything - it will just provide additional value. if anybody is confused, they could easily use their own name (and break their scripts in case the function is not defined). i prefer overloading and backward compatibility to new name and breaking compatibility, but YMMV.

Comment: But it's not backwards-compatible - the intent is to return a *specific* return code, which is not `false`'s semantics. If you use `false 42` in an environment that doesn't include this function you'll get subtly unexpected results (likely a `1` return code). If you use a different name you'll get a clear error message if your environment is not configured as intended.

Comment: Sure but the point of backwards compatibility is the use case of the original command - i.e. return non-zero error code, which it does. This argument is an extension of that. You cannot expect exactly 1 - some unix flavors dont return 1. So the only unexpected case is false 0 - there i agree it should throw an error. Thats more of a philosophical topic of whether you like overloading or not. YMMV. If you dont, rename, if you do, dont. Pick your own poison. Neither is the golden bullet. We dont need to agree on that. Anybody reading this has enough background info to decide himself.

Answer (score 6):

Didn't find anything lighter than just a simple function:

```
function set_return() { return ${1:-0}; }
```

All other solutions like `(...)` or `[...]` or `false` might contain an external process call.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do this implicitly by running a command that is guaranteed to fail, before entering the `while` loop.

The canonical such command is, of course, `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but there's a much better answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
until
    #do something until it returns success
do
    :;
done
```

If you're looping until something is successful, then just do that something in the until section. You can put exactly the same code in the until section you were thinking you had to put in the do/done section. You aren't forced to write the code in the do/done section and then transfer its results back to the while or until.

Answer (score 2):

`$?` can contain a byte value between 0..255. Return numbers outside this range will be remapped to this range as if a bitwise and 255 was applied.

`exit value` - can be used to set the value, but is brutal since it will terminate a process/script.

`return value` - when used in a function is somewhat traditional.

`[[ ... ]]` - is good for evaluating boolean expressions.

Here is an example of `exit`:

```
# Create a subshell, but, exit it with an error code:
$( exit 34 ); echo $? # outputs: 34
```

Here are examples of `return`:

```
# Define a `$?` setter and test it:
set_return() { return $1; }
set_return 0; echo $? # outputs: 0
set_return 123; echo $? # outputs: 123
set_return 1000; echo $? # outputs: 232
set_return -1; echo $? # outputs: 255
```

Here are are examples of `[ ... ]`:

```
# Define and use a boolean test:
lessthan() { [[ $1 < $2 ]]; }
lessthan 3 8 && echo yes # outputs: yes
lessthan 8 3 && echo yes # outputs: nothing
```

Note, when using `$?` as a conditional, zero (0) means success, non-zero means failure.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this be what your looking for ?

```
#!/bin/bash
TEMPVAR=1
while [ $TEMPVAR -eq 1 ]
do
  #do something until it returns 0
  #construct the logic which will cause TEMPVAR to be set 0 then check for it in the 
  #if statement 

  if [ yourcodehere ]; then
     $TEMPVAR=0
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `until` to handle cases where `#do something until it returns 0` returns something other than 1 or 0:

```
#!/bin/bash

false
until [ $? -eq 0 ]
do
#do something until it returns 0    
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using

```sh
allow_return_code() {
  local LAST_RETURN_CODE=$?
  if [[ $LAST_RETURN_CODE -eq $1 ]]; then
    return 0
  else
    return $LAST_RETURN_CODE
  fi
}

# it converts 2 to 0, 
my-command-returns-2 || allow_return_code 2
echo $?
# 0

# and it preserves the return code other than 2
my-command-returns-8 || allow_return_code 2
echo $?
# 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using both "until" and the ":"

```
until curl -k "sftp://$Server:$Port/$Folder" --user "$usr:$pwd" -T "$filename";
do :;
```

done