# Re-start shell script without creating a new process in Linux

Tags: shell, loops, process, single-instance

I have a shell file which I execute then, at the end, I get the possibility to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and run it again. The problem is that each time I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> a new process is created and after 20 or 30 rounds I get 30 PIDs that will finally mess up my Linux. So, my question is: how can I make the script run always in the same process, instead of creating a new one each time I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>?

**Code:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Doing my stuff here!"

# Show message
read -sp "Press ENTER to re-start"
# Clear screen
reset
# Re-execute the script
./run_this.sh

exec $SHELL
```

Comment: You should use some sort of looping construct rather than a recursive execution.  If your test can be at the beginning, a simple while loop will do, if it needs to be at the end you might read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489809/emulating-do-while-loop-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to `exec` the script itself, like so

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Doing my stuff here!"

# Show message
read -sp "Press ENTER to re-start"
# Clear screen
reset
# Re-execute the script
exec bash ./run_this.sh
```

`exec` does not work with shell scripts, so you need to use execute `bash` instead with your script as an argument.

That said, an in-script loop is a better way to go.

```
while :; do
  echo "Doing my stuff here!"

  # Show message
  read -sp "Press ENTER to re-start"
  # Clear screen
  reset
done
```