# Does Linux Bash have a do-while loop?

Tags: linux, bash, do-while

After some search on the Internet, it appears that Bash doesn't have a *do-while* loop.

Is this correct? Is there a reliable source to confirm this (the lack of evidence that there is a *do-while* loop is not an argument that there isn't one, perhaps a statement is only *unpopular*)?

Is it possible to define directives oneself and thus implement a *do-while* loop? There is an algorithmic way to transform a *do-while*-loop in a *while*-loop, but this is **not** the scope of this question.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489809/emulating-do-while-loop-in-bash

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`bash` (or Posix shells in general) don't have an explicit syntax for a post-test loop (commonly known as a "do-while" loop) because the syntax would be redundant. The `while` compound statement allows you to write pre-test, post-test or mid-test loops, all with the same syntax.

Here's the semantics of a shell `while` loop, from [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_09):

> The format of the while loop is as follows:

```
while compound-list-1
do
  compound-list-2
done
```

> The compound-list-1 shall be executed, and if it has a non-zero exit status, the while command shall complete. Otherwise, the compound-list-2 shall be executed, and the process shall repeat.

A "compound list" is a sequence of commands; the exit status of a compound list is the exit status of the *last command* in the list.

That means that you could think of a `while` loop as being written as follows:

```
while
  optional-pre-test-compound-list
  condition
do
  post-test-compound-list
done
```

That is, *there is no requirement that the condition to be tested immediately follows the while keyword*. So the equivalent to the C syntax:

```
do statements while (test);
```

is

```
while statements; test do :; done
```

The `:` between the do and the done is required, because the shell grammar does not allow empty statements. Since `:` is not a metacharacter, it must have whitespace or a metacharacter before and after it; otherwise, it would be parsed as part of the preceding or succeeding token.  Since it's parsed as a command, it also needs a semicolon or newline after it; otherwise the `done` is treated as an argument to `:`.

Answer (score 4):

No, bash has no `do-while` loop. The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) section [3.2.4.1 Looping Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) lists `until`, `while` and `for`. **Note** there is no `do-while`.