# How to output the stack create successful info until all the resources are created in the stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a stack with `aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name ... --template-body file://...` to create a stack. It output the stack id as soon as I execute the command. But the resources which are required by the stack are stilling in creating.

I want to output some message until the all the resources are created.

I don't want to describe the stack in a loop. and output the message until got the stack create completed signal.

Answer (score 22):

After the initial create-stack request you will need to request another one:

```
 aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete --stack-name $STACK_ID_FROM_CREATE_STACK
```

From the aws docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/wait/stack-create-complete.html

> Wait until stack status is CREATE_COMPLETE. It will poll every 30
>   seconds until a successful state has been reached. This will exit with
>   a return code of 255 after 120 failed checks.

Comment: Do you know what happens if the stack goes into CREATE_FAILED instead? Will the command still take 60 minutes (30 seconds * 120) to fail, or will if fail as soon as the stack enters the CREATE_FAILED state?

Comment: i am facing Rate Exceeded exception frequently. Is there a way to configure the poll interval?

Answer (score 5):

I also needed a wait in my bash script after running `aws cloudformation create-stack`. I was hesitant to use the `aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete` command as it only polls up to 60 minutes (120 times 30 seconds). Also, I did not want to run tests to see how it would behave if the stack ended up in a state other than "CREATE_COMPLETE". I therefore wrote my own wait in bash as follows:

```
aws --region ${AWS_REGION} --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} cloudformation create-stack --template-body ${STACK_TEMPLATE} --stack-name ${STACK_NAME}
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    # Wait for create-stack to finish
    echo  "Waiting for create-stack command to complete"
    CREATE_STACK_STATUS=$(aws --region ${AWS_REGION} --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${STACK_NAME} --query 'Stacks[0].StackStatus' --output text)
    while [[ $CREATE_STACK_STATUS == "REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS" ]] || [[ $CREATE_STACK_STATUS == "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS" ]]
    do
        # Wait 30 seconds and then check stack status again
        sleep 30
        CREATE_STACK_STATUS=$(aws --region ${AWS_REGION} --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${STACK_NAME} --query 'Stacks[0].StackStatus' --output text)
    done
fi
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489809/emulating-a-do-while-loop-in-bash