# do while loop examples

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I try to test do while loop in linux but showing error.
script:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=10
do
{
echo "hello user"
} while(a <=20);
```

showing error:
w.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
w.sh: line 4:`do'

please help me out to solve my query.

Comment: You're mixing C syntax and shell syntax. Please look at some tutorials.

Comment: Hi, thanks for viewing my post, can you please reply with proper syntax of do while loop in linux/unix in bash shell.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, there isn't a simple do-while loop.

At first: the (normal) while loop

```
while <condition>; do
    <code>
done
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16489942/10871900) states, you can emulate a do-while loop with a function or a `break`:

```
loopBody{
    <code>
}
loopBody
while <condition>; do
    loopBody
done
```

or

```
while true; do
    <code>
    condition || break
done
```