# How to run loop of bash script

Tags: bash, active-directory

I'm new to Bash scripts.

I have this script

@echo off&&powershell -NoE -c "&{ipmo activedirectory; set-adaccountpassword (read-host 'user') -R}"

this script is running connecting to AD and then it's asking for the user and then I can reset a password for the user that I will type and then the script ends.

can someone help to do run this screen in a loop until I will type "done"?

thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Loop are design to run repetitive tasks.
To have interrupt from the user you may create **do** **while** loop and try to keep a condition check on while statement with your **done** condition. Check this question and posted answer for do while concept
[emulating-a-do-while-loop-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489809/emulating-a-do-while-loop-in-bash)

Comment: Hi, I don't have any experience with bash can you help me?

Comment: @Alexxx55555 in above comment i have given link which has good examples. One of the example :  ** #!/bin/bash
while [[ $STATUS != 0 ]]
    ssh-add -l &>/dev/null; STATUS="$?"
    if [[ $STATUS == 127 ]]; then echo "ssh not instaled" && exit 0;
    elif [[ $STATUS == 2 ]]; then echo "running ssh-agent.." && eval `ssh-agent` > /dev/null;
    elif [[ $STATUS == 1 ]]; then echo "get session identity.." && expect $HOME/agent &> /dev/null;
    else ssh-add -l && git submodule update --init --recursive --remote --merge && return 0; fi
do true; done **

Comment: Please upvote the post and suggestions if you are fine with the feedback

Comment: sorry no idea i just want to run this scriipt again can you help?